# Browser only applies css from first dynamically added style element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please view the following code:

```js
let elStyle = document.createElement('style');
elStyle.type = 'text/css';
elStyle.title = "dynamic";
elStyle.innerHTML = ".testclass{padding: 50px;}";
document.head.appendChild(elStyle);

elStyle = document.createElement('style');
elStyle.type = 'text/css';
elStyle.title = "dynamic2";
elStyle.innerHTML = ".testclass2{margin: 50px;}";
document.head.appendChild(elStyle);

let divel = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(divel);
divel.classList.add('testclass');
divel.classList.add('testclass2');
```

It dynamically creates two distinct `<style>` elements and appends them to the dom's head.
Afterwards, a `<div>` element is created dynamically as well and is appended to the dom's body. Then we add to the div element both classes contained respectively in our dynamically added style elements.

In Chrome and Firefox, if you inspect the div element you will see that only the CSS for the first class (testclass) is applied (in our case a `padding: 50px;`). In MSEdge, both classes' CSS is properly applied.

Is this intended behavior for Chrome/FF or bug?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Added the code for history purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the elements being dynamically added.

You have given the style elements `title`s, which marks them as being [*alternative* stylesheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Alternative_style_sheets) which shouldn't be used together.

If you remove the `title` attributes, both will apply.

```js
let elStyle = document.createElement('style');
elStyle.type = 'text/css';
elStyle.innerHTML = ".testclass{padding: 50px;}";
document.head.appendChild(elStyle);

elStyle = document.createElement('style');
elStyle.type = 'text/css';
elStyle.innerHTML = ".testclass2{margin: 50px;}";
document.head.appendChild(elStyle);

let divel = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(divel);
divel.classList.add('testclass');
divel.classList.add('testclass2');
```